# Remove specific json serializer dependency and use a general interface

Tags: c#, .net, json

We are using the JSON.NET reference through the whole solution. So, our solution is strong dependent in JSON.NET serializer. We would like to create a generic interface, e.g. `IJsonSerializer`, and use this one rather than a specific implementation. Then, If we change the implementation, It would be easy to do, just inject the right dependency:

e.g.

```
container.Register<IJsonSerializer, JsonConvert>();
container.Register<IJsonSerializer, JilSerializer>();
```

Would be it possible?

Comment: Is changing JSON serializers something you find yourself doing on a regular basis? Just curious. I'd no more consider that an interesting feature to have in my project than, say, an ability to switch to a different `String` implementation. Not *everything* needs to be behind an interface.

Comment: We are considering using Jil rather than JSON.NET. If we use Jil and we need to move back, we don't want to refactor all code again.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer to your question is "yes". Of course you can create a generic interface. Of course, *you* have to decide what that generic interface looks like based on your code's needs, and you have to write the adapters that conform to the interface. Ideally, this interface needs to be small, otherwise it would be more work than doing a case study of which framework is right for you (that is, figuring out what would make you "move back" in advance to make sure it's not going to be necessary in the first place).